# how change this snippet to resize shapes from one side not two-sided - html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, resize, html5-canvas

I have this snippet code for resizing shapes in canvas:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#canvas{
width: 500px;
height:500px;
}
</style>

<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" style="border:2px solid black;" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<script>
$(function(){

var cvs = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = cvs.getContext('2d'),
    mousedown = {},
    dragging = false,
    params = {cx:200,cy:200,w:30,h:80,angle:0},
    editStarted = false,
    offset = {};

function rect(ctx,params) {
    var w = params.w ,
        h = params.h ,
        angle = params.angle,
        cx = params.cx,
        cy = params.cy;

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cvs.width,cvs.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.translate(cx, cy);
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    ctx.rect(-w/2, -h/2, w, h);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}

function drawRuberband (ctx,params,what,loc) {

    var w = params.w ,
        h = params.h ,
        angle = params.angle,
        cx = params.cx,
        cy = params.cy,
        ok = false;

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(cx,cy);
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    if (what == 'onlypath') {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(-w/2, -h/2, w, h);
        ctx.moveTo(0,-h/2-30);
        ctx.arc(0, -h/2-30,3,0,Math.PI*2);
        if(ctx.isPointInPath(loc.x,loc.y)) ok = true;
    }
    else if (what == 'rotate') {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0,-h/2-30,3,0,Math.PI*2);
        if(ctx.isPointInPath(loc.x,loc.y)) ok = true;
    }
    else if (what == 'wh') {    
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(-w/2-4,-h/2-4,8,8);
        ctx.rect(w/2-4,-h/2-4,8,8);
        ctx.rect(w/2-4, h/2-4, 8, 8);
        ctx.rect(-w/2-4, h/2-4, 8, 8);
        if(ctx.isPointInPath(loc.x,loc.y)) ok = true;
    }
    else if (what == 'h') {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(-4, -h/2-4, 8, 8);
        ctx.rect(-4, h/2-4, 8, 8);
        if(ctx.isPointInPath(loc.x,loc.y)) ok = true;
    }
    else if (what == 'w') {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(w/2-4, -4, 8, 8);
        ctx.rect(-w/2-4, -4, 8, 8);
        if(ctx.isPointInPath(loc.x,loc.y)) {
            ok = true;
        }
    }
    else if (what == 'in') {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(-w/2, -h/2, w, h);
        if(ctx.isPointInPath(loc.x,loc.y)) ok = true;
    }
    else {
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(156, 89, 89, 0.62)';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.62)';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(-w/2, -h/2, w, h);
        ctx.moveTo(0, -h/2);
        ctx.lineTo(0, -h/2-30);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(-w/2-4, -h/2-4, 8, 8);
        ctx.rect(-4, -h/2-4, 8, 8);
        ctx.rect(w/2-4, -h/2-4, 8, 8);
        ctx.rect(w/2-4, -4, 8, 8);
        ctx.rect(w/2-4, h/2-4, 8, 8);
        ctx.rect(-4, h/2-4, 8, 8);
        ctx.rect(-w/2-4, h/2-4, 8, 8);
        ctx.rect(-w/2-4, -4, 8, 8);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.62)';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0, -h/2-30,3,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();
    }

    ctx.restore();

    if (ok) return true;
    return false;
}

function windowToCanvas(x, y) {
    var bbox = cvs.getBoundingClientRect();
    return { x: x - bbox.left * (cvs.width / bbox.width), y: y - bbox.top * (cvs.height / bbox.height)};
}

cvs.onmousedown = function (e) {
    var loc = windowToCanvas(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    mousedown.x = loc.x;
    mousedown.y = loc.y;
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent cursor change


    if(drawRuberband(ctx,params,'onlypath',loc) || editStarted) {
        dragging = true;
    }

    offset.x = mousedown.x - params.cx;
    offset.y = mousedown.y - params.cy;
    offset.angle = Math.atan2(mousedown.y - params.cy, mousedown.x - params.cx);

};

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    var loc = windowToCanvas(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent selections

    if (dragging && editStarted) {
        var a1 = loc.x - params.cx,
            b1 = loc.y - params.cy,
            a2 = Math.abs(a1 * Math.cos(-params.angle) - b1 * Math.sin(-params.angle)),
            b2 = Math.abs(b1 * Math.cos(-params.angle) + a1 * Math.sin(-params.angle));

        if (editStarted == 'w') {
            params.w = a2*2;
        }
        else if (editStarted == 'h') {
            params.h = b2*2;
        }
        else if (editStarted == 'wh') {
            params.w = a2*2;
            params.h = b2*2;
        }
        else if (editStarted == 'in') {
            params.cx = loc.x - offset.x;
            params.cy = loc.y - offset.y;
        }
        else if (editStarted == 'rotate') {
            params.angle = Math.atan2(loc.x - params.cx, - (loc.y - params.cy ));
        }

        rect(ctx,params);
        drawRuberband(ctx,params);
    }
    else {
        var move = false;

        if (drawRuberband(ctx,params,'rotate',loc)){
            editStarted = 'rotate';
        }
        else if (drawRuberband(ctx,params,'wh',loc)){
            editStarted = 'wh';
        }
        else if (drawRuberband(ctx,params,'w',loc)){
            editStarted = 'w';
        }
        else if (drawRuberband(ctx,params,'h',loc)){
            editStarted = 'h';
        }
        else if (drawRuberband(ctx,params,'in',loc)){
            move = true;
            editStarted = 'in';
        }
        else {
            editStarted = false;
        }

        if (move) cvs.style.cursor = 'move';
        else cvs.style.cursor = 'default';
    }

}).mouseup(function (e) {

    if (dragging) {
        dragging = false;
    }
});

    rect(ctx,params);
    drawRuberband(ctx,params);

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

my problem this is that when I resize shape from one side (for example right side). it resizes from two-side (right and left). I want it only resize from one side.

how change code to solve my problem ??

Comment: I would recommend using a canvas library like createjs, kineticjs or fabricjs. They all solved this problem already.

Comment: I want to add some special abilities and for this reason I must use my own script not libraries. Please help to improve this code :)

Comment: The general idea is to translate a shape when it's being scaled. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/j44up/ I've implemented only width change, but it would work the same for height. Notice that after you rotate the shape, it doesn't scale properly. You need to take angle into consideration when translating. Some geometrical equations could be useful. Good luck:)

Comment: your code dont resize right in rotations

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote in previous comment.